set 4 PM by default in time selection for React DateTimePicker
I am working on React DateTimePicker where I need to set time to 4 PM but do not show that value in datetimepicker input field instead show only after datetimepicker icon click. How to set 4 PM by default in time selection for React DateTimePicker? I am able to set the time to current date to today date and time to 4 PM suppose as "14-Sep-2024 04:00 PM" but value is showing by default on the page load. Instead as per my requirement I have to show only on date selection.
My code is
import { DateTimePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DateTimePicker';
----------------
----------------
----------------
<DateTimePicker name={'myDatePickerValue'}
  disablePast
  onChange={(date) => {
     handleMyDatePickerValueChange(date)
  }}                                                                                                          
  value={myDatePickerValue? dayjs(myDatePickerValue) : dayjs().hour(16).minute(0).second(0).millisecond(0) }
  format="DD-MMM-YYYY hh:mm A"
  minDateTime={dayjs()}             
/>

As per my requirement, I don't want to show the input value in the datetimepicker input because I need to show as "DD-MMM-YYYY hh:mm A" initially and I have to show the value only after user selects the value from datetimepicker icon. I only need to show current date and time as 4 PM after clicking on datepicker icon only.
Any help in this?

Sounds like everything is working correctly.  You'll need to add custom CSS to do what you need.  Ultimately, this requirement makes no sense though.  Inputs should always show the values they hold.

but here I don't want to show the input value in the datetimepicker input because as per my requirement I need to show as "DD-MMM-YYYY hh:mm A" initially and I have to show the value only after user selects the value from datetimepicker icon. I also need to show current date and time as 4 PM after clicking on datepicker icon only.

After a lot of effort, I wrote below solution on my own:

<DateTimePicker 
  value={dayjs(myDatePicker)} 
  onChange={handleMyDatePickerChange} 
  disablePast
  format="DD-MMM-YYYY hh:mm A"
  minDateTime={dayjs()}
  slotProps={{
      textField: {
      readOnly: true,
    },
  }} 
/>

const handleMyDatePickerChange = (date: any) => {
    const dateValue = getDateValue(date);
    setmyDatePicker(dateValue);
};

const getDateValue = (date: any) => {
    if (date === null) return null;

    const selectedDate = dayjs(date.$d).date();
    const selectedMonth = dayjs(date.$d).month();
    const myDatePickerValue = myDatePicker ? dayjs(optionExpiryDate).date() : null;
    const myDatePickerMonthValue = myDatePicker ? dayjs(myDatePicker).month() : null;
    const todayDate = dayjs().date()
    const currentMonth = dayjs().month()
    const currentHours = dayjs().hour()

    if (date.isBefore(dayjs())) {
        return handlePastDate(date, selectedDate, myDatePickerValue, todayDate, currentHours);
    } else if (date.isAfter(dayjs())) {
        return handleFutureDate(date, selectedDate, selectedMonth, myDatePickerValue, myDatePickerMonthValue, todayDate, currentMonth);
    } else {
        return date;
    }
};

const handlePastDate = (date, selectedDate, myDatePickerValue, todayDate, currentHours) => {
    if (selectedDate === myDatePickerValue) {
        if (dayjs().hour() <= dayjs(date.$d).hour()) {
            return date;
        } else {
            return dayjs(new Date());
        }
    } else {
        if ((myDatePickerValue === null || selectedDate === myDatePickerValue || selectedDate === todayDate) && currentHours <= 16) {
            return dayjs(date.$d).hour(16).minute(0).second(0).millisecond(0);
        } else {
            return dayjs(new Date());
        }
    }
};

const handleFutureDate = (date, selectedDate, selectedMonth, myDatePickerValue, myDatePickerMonthValue, todayDate, currentMonth) => {
    if (selectedDate === myDatePickerValue) {
        return date;
    } else {
        if(selectedDate === todayDate || selectedDate > todayDate || selectedMonth > currentMonth || selectedMonth > myDatePickerMonthValue){
            return dayjs(date.$d).hour(16).minute(0).second(0).millisecond(0)
        }else{
            return dayjs(new Date())
        }
    }
};

